# Asp.net core 3.1 backend does not get the Identity from cookie

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, identity, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I have vue.js frontend and asp.net core 3.1 backend. Backend uses SignInManager and Identity. I am trying to use cookie authentication. Api requests work from Postman(!!) roles are applied, everything, but do not from vue app (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false). Indentity is empty. Cookie is present in the HttpContext

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"]));
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers()
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(
            opts =>
            {
                opts.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            }
            )
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

       //some DI
       ...
       //
       }
```

bit more Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
```

I was trying to proxy requests to api in vue app. Did not help

```
module.exports = {
devServer: {
   proxy: {
     '^/api': {
       target: 'https://localhost:44376',
       ws: true,
       changeOrigin: true
     }
   }
  }
}
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing `AddRoles<IdentityRoles>()`?

```cs
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(
    opts =>
    {
        opts.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    }
)
.AddRoles<IdentityRoles>() .// <== this line
.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```